# How to select camera for "create signature" in PDF document in Preview 11.0

Tags: pdf, preview, webcam

I am trying to add a new signature to a document in Preview, but when I click on "Create Signature" to use the webcam attached, it instead wants to use the virtual camera defined in OBS, which is not even currently running. I imagine that I could go into OBS and hook up the camera and enable the virtual camera feed, but...

Can't I just select the camera I want to use in Preview? I don't see a way to do that.

Comment: I'm assuming you are referring to [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com).

Comment: Yes, I meant OBS Studio.

Comment: Did you figure this out?